# Letting $r \rightarrow 1$ in $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log |f(re^{i\theta})|\, d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $\{z: |z| \leq 1\}$, analytic on $\{z: |z| < 1\}$, and $f(0) \neq 0$. For $0 < r < 1$, consider the integral $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log |f(re^{i\theta})|\, d\theta.$$ Let $r_{n}$ be a sequence such that $\inf_{|z| = r_{n}}|f(z)| > 0$ and $r_{n} \rightarrow 1^{-}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Is $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log |f(r_{n}e^{i\theta})|\, d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log |f(e^{i\theta})|\, d\theta?$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to assume that $f(z)\neq 0$ for $|z|<1$. Note that $\ln|f(z)|$ is the real part of $\ln f(z)$ and
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{\ln f(z)}{z}dz=\ln f(0). $$
Hence
$$  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{\ln f(z)}{z}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r_n}\frac{\ln f(z)}{z}dz=\ln f(0). $$
Separate the real part from the imaginary part and use $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $z=r_ne^{i\theta}$ and you will get.

Comment: What if $f=0$ on $|z|=1$ ?